# Site on IIS 7.5 accessible via SSL on server, but not from local network

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5

I have a site set up on IIS 7.5.  I added the following binding...

type: https
Host Name: [Blank]
Port: 443
IP Address: `192.168.1.6`
Binding Information: [Blank]

I can access the site via `https://192.168.1.6` from the server itself.

When I try to access the site from another machine (`193.168.1.4`) on the same sub-net via `https://192.168.1.6`  I get no response.  `http://192.168.1.6` returns the site as expected.

I have used wireshark to examine the packets on the server, the first of which I have included as an image.

[image: SSL Problem]

There were two other packets, very similar to this. There was no response from the server.

[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: have you checked iis logs?

Comment: Yes, and on realizing that IIS was not seeing the request, I figured out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, It turned out to be a windows firewall issue.  I had not enabled the appropriate rule.  It is worth noting that wireshark (WinPCap) apparently gets to the packets before the firewall.  That is what threw me off.